# How can I make users read a popup without just clicking "ok" or "close"

Tags: javascript, popup, user-experience

I have a piece of software that gives a popup warning which alerts users that the action that they are about to do is irreversible.

From tests, and from personal experience, I know that most impatient users will just skip or hit ok on most popups because they think understand the implications of the action they are doing.

What is the best way to make sure users actually read a pop up before confirming?

Comment: Instead of "OK", the button could say "Confirm irreversible action".

Comment: include an input in the popup - make part of the warning something like "enter the word **banana** and click OK to proceed" - check that they have indeed entered the word banana in the input

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ux.stackexchange.com is the place to ask user experience questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a complete solution. Everyone struggles with this.

I would use one of the following:

- Time (Set a 5 second timer, after that the action buttons appear)
- Get the user to enter something via text box to confirm they read it (e.g. type XYZ to continue)
- Use color, animation and imagery to convey that its a potentially dangerous action (Make it red, shake and have a big X symbol or something.

Comment: Thanks these are good suggestions. I never thought about a mandatory text confirmation, although you get those all the time on GitHub.